# Open-URI not following redirects (Not sure)

Tags: ruby, curl, mechanize, open-uri

I have this situation where I have to read this url in ruby:

`http://tamilnadu.schools9.com/anna-university-grade-system-chennai.aspx?htno=211511104125`

Now, when I do

```
require 'open-uri'
open "http://tamilnadu.schools9.com/anna-university-grade-system-chennai.aspx?htno=211511104125"
```

nothing happens! Im having to interrupt it to stop. I was puzzled because it worked fine from browser.

But then I tried curl and I got:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/anna-university-grade-system-chennai.aspx?htno=211511104125&amp;AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Then I tried `curl -L` and I got the document.

Why does this happen? I read `open-uri` follows redirects automatically.
How do I do this?

Comment: It's probably a cookies issue. Have you tried to send the request with a cookie file with _AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1_ ?

Comment: No I have not. Will try. Btw, doing a get with `mechanize` is working fine. Ill try with cookie and open-uri.

Comment: This seems to be a html redirection and not a header redirection that's supported by `Open-URI`.

Comment: Ahh that adds clarity. Why is it not supported by Open-URI? I dont see an option to enable it as well.